# How do I shout or use other powers with the new Kinect update - without speaking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, kinect

I don't want to use the voice commands because my wife is sleeping.  When I press RB it just changes the little speaker icon. How do I shout without shouting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, it's LB + RB...

Comment: So you figured out how to shout without speaking...  that sounds like a good name for a band :) .